# How indexOf is not working on this scenario?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

this is my array,

```
var myArray =[{ a: 'b'}, { b: 'b'}, { c: 'b'},{ g: 'b'}];
```

But when i used indexOf, its not working,

```js
var myArray =[{ a: 'b'}, { b: 'b'}, { c: 'b'},{ g: 'b'}]
var myObj = { g: 'b'};

var isInArray = myArray.indexOf(myObj);

console.log(isInArray)
```

Whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

[`Array.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Description) compares `searchElement` to elements of the `Array` using strict equality (the same method used by the `===` or triple-equals operator).

In your case, `myObj` is not the same as the similar object contained in the `array`, hence it cannot be found.

For further details, please take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201471/2358409).

Comment: Why its not same ? what difference it makes ?

Comment: This may help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate the array and the entried of the wanted object and check if key and value match.

```js
const
    array =[{ a: 'b' }, { b: 'b' }, { c: 'b' }, { g: 'b' }],
    object = { g: 'b' },
    isInArray = array.some(o =>
        Object.entries(object).every(([k, v]) => k in o && o[k] === v)
    );

console.log(isInArray);
```

Comment: I have asked, why i cant find index of that.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to find out if a particular value is in an `Object` array I would just write it like this

```js
var myArray = [{
  a: 'b'
}, {
  b: 'b'
}, {
  c: 'b'
}, {
  g: 'b'
}]
var myObj = { g: 'b' };

for (i in myArray) {
  if (myArray[i] == myObj) {
    console.log('Value exists')
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Two way to resolve

```js
// Example #1
// Add " on each items
var myArray =["{ a: 'b'}", "{ b: 'b'}", "{ c: 'b'}","{ g: 'b'}"]
var myObj = "{ g: 'b'}";

var isInArray = myArray.indexOf(myObj);

console.log(isInArray)


/*
* OR Try this method
*/

// Example #2
var myArray2 =[{ a: 'b'}, { b: 'b'}, { c: 'b'},{ g: 'b'}]

var isInArray2 = myArray2.map(function(e) {
                    return e.g; // <-- 'g:' from array
                  }).indexOf('b'); // <-- 'b' from array

console.log(isInArray2)
```